# Does spark rearranges the order of fields in a dataframe internally in alphabetical order?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, schema

I am creating a spark streaming job which reads JSON messages from a Kafka Topic.For every RDD i am getting from Dstream,i am creating a dataframe.My requirement is to write this dataframe to an hdfs path.before writing, i need to check the schema of this message whether it is in correct format or not.
So i have created a StructType customSchema with expected fields in same order as in the JSON message in Kafka topic.I am trying to compare the two but this doesnt work.Even when all fields are present in correct order,it results as false.

I have a json file in the same format as in Kafka topic.

```
{"transactionId":"12345","accountName":"XXX1","sessionKey":"WEB","description":"INR"}
```

I created a dataframe around it

```
val df=spark.read.json("/data/path/sample/")

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- accountName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sessionKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- transactionId: string (nullable = true)
```

Note:When i am printing the schema of df i created,it is printing in alphabetical order.

I created a customSchema of StructType

```
scala> val schema1=  StructType( Array (StructField("transactionId",StringType, true),StructField("accountName",StringType, true),StructField("sessionKey",StringType, true),StructField("description",StringType, true)))
schema1: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(transactionId,StringType,true), StructField(accountName,StringType,true), StructField(sessionKey,StringType,true), StructField(description,StringType,true))
```

When i tried to match it,it results as false

```
scala> val d=df.schema==schema1
            d: Boolean = false
```

it results as false with .equals method as well
Now if i create my customSchema in the same way as printSchema is printing,

```
scala> val schema2=  StructType( Array (StructField("accountName",StringType, true),StructField("description",StringType, true),StructField("sessionKey",StringType, true),StructField("transactionId",StringType, true)))
schema2: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(accountName,StringType,true), StructField(description,StringType,true), StructField(sessionKey,StringType,true), StructField(transactionId,StringType,true))
```

and if i compare the two now,it works fine as expected.

```
scala> val j=df.schema==schema2
            j: Boolean = true
```

So based on my observations,does spark rearranges the order of fields internally in alphabetical order because i could not find it in documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark Json infers schema if it is not provided.
If columns is needed in particular order `select` is better option.

```
val colsArr = Array("col1","col2","col3")
val df = df.select(colsArr.head,colsArr.tail:_*)
```

Comment: yes it does but why it is rearranging it in alphabetical order and not in the order the fields are in the Json?

Comment: is it a normal behaviour in spark in read.json method because i could not get any documentation suggesting this?